# Why do have most (Windows) programs such 'complicated' setup programs?

Tags: windows, installation, uninstall

There seems to do a lot of complicated stuff going on - that also make it hard to uninstall when (i.e.) the original uninstaller breaks down.

Why isn't it just as simple as:

- Unzip all unique files to a folder.
- Unzip (optionally) some shared dlls/libraries to a shared system folder
- Setup some registry settings (could be done on startup of the program).

I know this is probably a bit **too much** of an oversimplification, but still..

I'm talking about bigger applications like Visual Studio, Office, Adobe suit, Maya, etc.

Comment: Because Windows from his historical roots always gave programs the control where to put stuff. If they wanted to install themselves to %APPDATA% they could, and so on. So it is on the installers side to provide options.  Linux/Unix/similar "force" programs into a specific scheme which gives the user easier control as there are not all programs to manage individually but rather all via the system. This has pros and cons. Windows has eg. the DLL-Hell, other OSes dependency-Hell etc.

Comment: Windows does have a share system folder.  Registry settings are also at times handled by an launcher application.  Even your third statement is true, a installer actually is an archive, which can be extracted manually if you wanted.

Comment: Programs use to run from the program folder with no dependencies in the Windows 98 days, I still have a bunch of them, to transfer the program to another PC you just copied the program folder for that application to another PC, done, I miss those days. Programs have become more complicated just like everything else in life, cars, houses, spouses, taxes, work....

Answer (score 2):

In your step 2, what if I install two programs that both add the same file to the shared folder? Then what happens when I uninstall one of them?

Its not hard to install a program, it really is as simple as you describe. It is hard to ***uninstall*** a program and not have other programs that shared files/registry entries not break.

The ability to track the "reference count" of files and registry settings to handle shared components is where the bulk of the "complicatedness" comes from for a installer.

Comment: Not to mention that you need to keep track of where all those shared items are actually stored and what versions they are, especially where programs only work with specific versions and you have to have multiple versions able to co-exist on one system... more complexity.